# Opening QGIS using VBA and executing Python script?

Tags: qgis, python, vba

Using VBA, I want to open QGIS (the actual GUI) and execute a simple script through the Python console or the editor.

Comment: would shell help? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe736fyk(v=vs.90).aspx I seem to recall that this was a VBA function.

Comment: but shell would just start QGIS, it wouldn't go further
i want to run a script inside the python console or editor after starting QGIS

Comment: That's true. Sometimes programs take command line arguments which would allow you to give QGIS instructions... Shell is a single command so when I used it I wrote to a batch file and shelled the batch file and deleted it when it was done. As for getting inside QGIS with VBA then no, you can't do that.

Comment: Can't it be done with Python, create a .py that can open QGIS and start a script in the Python console/editor?

Comment: I think so, that's just a very slight modification of the write to batch and then shell. I've also done that before but in SML for TntMips.

Comment: can you please tell me how, or where to search?

Comment: I'm not an expert in QGIS by any means. Hopefully someone else will pick up this thread and reveal how to do that.

Answer (score 6):

QGIS can take a `--code` that you can pass a Python file to in order to run.

```
qgis --code my myfile.py
```

Run this command from the VBA shell command.

Comment: I used Shell ("C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS Valmiera\bin\qgis.bat --core my test.py"), but when QGIS starts it gives an error "Layer is not valid, the layer C:\Users\Home\Documents\--core is not a valid layer and can not be added to the map", can you please explain how to use this command.

Comment: I tried --code not --core and it worked, thanks a lot

Comment: Beware of spaces in path names, it looks like it opens in "c:\users\home\documents" by default. If you want to use a file called "my test.py" it should be quoted or it becomes two arguments at the command line, best to call it "my_test.py"

Comment: It works fine, thank you. 
How can i can run another .py in the same QGIS instance, if I use the Shell command again, it opens another instance.

Comment: You don't have a lot of options.  The only option that would allow communication like that is maybe some kind of COM object using Python and connect to it in VBA. Python can expose a class as a COM object.